# Chrome Opening From VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try run any program with F5 in VS Code it opens a localhost site from chrome, is there a way to disable this as it is incredibly annoying?

Changed some keyboard shortcuts but nothing worked, like start without debugging.

*PROBLEM SOLVED*

There was a little option in the bottom left that said 'launch chrome against localhost' so I just witched it over to python.

Comment: Welcome! Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: Hi Harry Bertie, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it instead editing the problem and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)